# Copy PDF's to Folder using batch

Tags: file, pdf, batch-file, copy, directory

I want to copy several unique PDF files to a unique folder.

The folders already exists.

For example

C:\Document\240C03881_10.pdf Copy this one to : C:\Endresult\240C03881\240C03881_10.pdf
C:\Document\240C03882_10.pdf Copy this one to : C:\Endresult\240C03882\240C03882_10.pdf
C:\Document\240C03883_10.pdf Copy this one to : C:\Endresult\240C03883\240C03883_10.pdf

The script should only read the first 9 digits. The script may not read _10.
Example,
Script sees 240C03881_10. But read it as 240C03881. The script is going to look if the 240C03881 folder exists. If not, the script ends/ignores it. If it does exists, it places the .pdf to its corresponding location.

This is the script i currently have, but nothing happens.. anyone? :

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Process all .pdf files
for %%a in (*.pdf) do (
rem Get just the file name, ie: "888123AA"
set fileName=%%~Na
rem Using the file name minus two last chars, ie: "888123"
rem get the default folder with that name
for /D %%b in (*-!fileName:~0,-3!-*) do ( 
rem And copy the file to that folder
copy "%%a" "%%b" 

)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for %%p in (*.pdf) do for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%n in ("%%~np") do (
    copy "%%~fp" "c:\endresult\%%~n\%%~nxp"
)
```

Comment: You have to run it in the folder with the PDF files.  Report any error messages on the console.  Put `pause` as the last line if you don't see the console screen.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but i want it to run it from my Desktop. Is that possible ?

Comment: Okay got it, using the PUSHD variable. My VERY last question is.. Is it also possible to only transfer the PDF's that are created this day?  So for example, i run the script daily. And it only copies the pdf's that are created that day.